# SQL Case on Where clause to different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to get a query that, based on a given condition (if isCurrent = 1 or not) should give me just one value/row based on the CurriculumId /which will be a parameter on a stored procedure).
This value should, in case isCurrent = 1 return to me the item with the most current StartDate but if isCurrent = 0 then it should give me the one with the most current EndDate.

The thing is that I only want one item per CurriculumId, ideally the one with isCurrent = 1 and the most current StartDate (ignoring the remaining rows) but, if there are no experiences with isCurrent = 1, then it should return to me the one with the most current EndDate.

My previous query was almost working but I still got the one with the most current StartDate (isCurrent = 1) AND the one with the most current EndDate when I want to retrieve just one or another.

I've come to the query bellow:

```
SELECT table.IntProfessionalExperienceId,
    table.IsCurrent,
    table.StartDate,
    table.EndDate
FROM table
WHERE table.CurriculumId = 12
AND
CASE table.IsCurrent
WHEN 1
THEN
    table.StartDate = (
            SELECT max(table.StartDate)
            FROM table
            WHERE table.IsCurrent = 1 
            AND table.CurriculumId = 12
            GROUP BY table.CurriculumId
    )
ELSE
      table.EndDate = (
        SELECT max(table.EndDate)
        FROM table
        WHERE table.CurriculumId = 12
        GROUP BY table.CurriculumId
    )
END
```

Individually, the queries seem to be working OK and returning the supposed value although when ran as a whole I get the following errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

What in my syntax is wrong? I know from reading the errors what is wrong with the query but I just don't know how to fix it. And is it just the syntax or am I doing the query wrong to start with?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* and is meant to produce a *value*. Look again at what you're trying to do and you should realise that you don't need it - you just need to combine bits of your logic using `AND`s and `OR`s. (i.e. `(IsCurrent = 1 AND StartDate = ...) OR (IsCurrent<>1 AND EndDate = ...)`

Comment: You cannot use "table.StartDate =" after THEN, this is wrong. Just directly write the value.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each row a rank in its curriculumid group, using ROW_NUMBER with an appropriate order by clause. Then only take the records ranked 1 (i.e. best matching).

```
select
  intprofessionalexperienceid,
  iscurrent,
  startdate,
  enddate
from
(
  select mytable.*
  row_number() over 
  (
    partition by curriculumid 
    order by 
      case when iscurrent = 1 then 1 else 2 end, 
      case when iscurrent = 1 then startdate else enddate end desc
  ) as rn
  from mytable
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

(I know this doesn't actually answer your question, but is the straight-forward way to approach the problem in my opinion.)

Comment: This was the perfect solution. Using a ranking system seems to be the right way to go at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Split this into multiple conditions, like this:

```
SELECT 
    table.IntProfessionalExperienceId,
    table.IsCurrent,
    table.StartDate,
    table.EndDate
FROM table
WHERE 
    table.CurriculumId = 12 AND
      (
        (
            Table.IsCurrent = 1 AND 
            table.StartDate = 
              (
                SELECT max(table.StartDate)
                FROM table
                WHERE 
                    table.IsCurrent = 1 AND 
                    table.CurriculumId = 12
                GROUP BY table.CurriculumId
              )
        ) OR 
        (
            ISNULL(table.IsCurrent,0) != 1 AND
            table.EndDate = 
              (
                SELECT max(table.EndDate)
                FROM table
                WHERE table.CurriculumId = 12
                GROUP BY table.CurriculumId
              )
        )
      )
```

EDIT: another, arguably simpler approach would be to pre-aggregate the data you want in your WHERE clause so that you only need to call it a single time, rather than evaluate each row separately.  Something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    table.IntProfessionalExperienceId,
    table.IsCurrent,
    table.StartDate,
    table.EndDate
FROM 
    table
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            MAX(table.EndDate) AS MaxEndDate, 
            MAX(CASE WHEN table.IsCurrent = 1 THEN table.StartDate END) AS MaxCurrentStartDate
        FROM table 
        WHERE CurriculumID = 12 
      ) MaxDates ON 
        (Table.IsCurrent = 1 AND Table.StartDate = MaxDates.MaxCurrentStartDate) OR
        (ISNULL(Table.IsCurrent, 0) != 1 AND Table.EndDate = MaxDates.MaxEndDate)
WHERE 
    table.CurriculumId = 12
```

Comment: Although that would look simpler there still is the same problem with the query: I'm getting the most recent current record and the most recent "closed" record when I really want is either one or another, but not both, i.e., if theres a current one, give me the most recent one to me. if not, give me the most recent closed one.

Comment: So, let me see if I understand ... you want to check if current record exists first (and if so, return the one started most recently), and then if no current record exists you want to show the most recently finished one?

Comment: That's exactly that. Maybe I over explained myself to the point of confusion?

Comment: I'd say the problem is more that you presented code that, even if it worked with no errors, didn't actually do what you were hoping.  Maybe next time include both the code and a description of what you want it to do? I think I've got it now, give me a minute to update with the new query.

Comment: Have you tried the answer by ThorstenKettner? Based on your new description, that looks to me like it will do as you are asking, assuming you have access to windowed functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: I did. The results didn't make sense to me at the time so I moved on to try another suggestions. I don't exactly understand what ROW_NUMBER() does, but I'll look into it and see if it fts my needs. I'm using this to avoid "hacking" at Lucene (related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058253/lucene-retrieve-values-based-on-conditional-of-two-fields)

Comment: When you've had a chance to review his results, let us know what is going on and we can try to help further.

Comment: ThorstenKettner's answer was perfect. Thank you for you help because I still learnt something from you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `CASE` statemen this way:

```
SELECT table.IntProfessionalExperienceId,
    table.IsCurrent,
    table.StartDate,
    table.EndDate
FROM table
WHERE table.CurriculumId = 12
AND table.EndDate = CASE 
                      WHEN table.IsCurrent = 1
                      THEN (
                             SELECT max(table.StartDate)
                             FROM table
                             WHERE table.IsCurrent = 1 
                             AND table.CurriculumId = 12
                             GROUP BY table.CurriculumId
                           )
                      ELSE
                           (
                             SELECT max(table.EndDate)
                             FROM table
                             WHERE table.CurriculumId = 12
                             GROUP BY table.CurriculumId
                           )
                    END
```

Comment: I had already tried that. What you present is equivalent to what I wrote.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't look at it right. No I don't. No more errors. Just not getting the correct record since it's returning the one with an EndDate instead of the default: the most recent current record (basically when EndDate is null)